# In South migration history, is the "applied" date the beginning or end of the migration?

Tags: django-south

South has the `south_migrationhistory` table which records when migrations are applied.

```
  Column   |           Type           
-----------+--------------------------
 id        | integer                  
 app_name  | character varying(255)   
 migration | character varying(255)   
 applied   | timestamp with time zone
```

What exactly does the `applied` timestamp mean? Is it the time when a migration started, or a time when the migration completed?